# NGINX config help, Multiple Servers

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, dedicated-server

I am having an issue with NGINX , this could quite possibly be an easy fix then again could not be I just don't know that much about NGINX.

I have my NGINX config below which works great. But I have 3 other hard drives with the same script that are set up with subdomains. So to make a long story short I need to add more listening servers I guess,
I have www1.example.com as first domain

and then I have www2.example.com etc. Each subdomain is on its own hard drive and I need to point nginx to each one of those hard drives. Is there a way to add the into the NGINX config?

Here is the config file.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
worker_rlimit_sigpending 32768;

error_log  logs/error.log  error;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  off;
    limit_conn_log_level info;

    #sendfile       on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    server_tokens off;
    autoindex off;

    keepalive_timeout  0;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m;
    perl_modules  perl;
    perl_require  download.pm;

    server {
        listen       182;
        server_name  example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        #charset koi8-r;

        location /nstatus {
            stub_status on;
            #allow 127.0.0.1;
            #deny all;
                        }

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /d/ {
            perl  download::handler;
        }

        # Free
        location /download_f/ {
            alias /example.com/uploads/;
            internal;
            set $limit_rate $arg_speed;
            limit_conn one 5;
        }

        # Registered
        location /download_r/ {
            alias /example.com/uploads/;
            internal;
            set $limit_rate $arg_speed;
            limit_conn one 5;
        }

        # Premium
        location /download_p/ {
            alias /example.com/uploads/;
            internal;
            set $limit_rate $arg_speed;
            limit_conn one 10;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

         server {
        listen       182;
        server_name  2.example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        #charset koi8-r;

        location /nstatus {
            stub_status on;
            #allow 127.0.0.1;
            #deny all;
                        }

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /d/ {
            perl  download::handler;
        }

        # Free
        location /download_f/ {
            alias /2.example.com/uploads/;
            internal;
            set $limit_rate $arg_speed;
            limit_conn one 5;
        }

        # Registered
        location /download_r/ {
            alias /2.example.com/uploads/;
            internal;
            set $limit_rate $arg_speed;
            limit_conn one 5;
        }

        # Premium
        location /download_p/ {
            alias /2.example.com/uploads/;
            internal;
            set $limit_rate $arg_speed;
            limit_conn one 10;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `root` directive in your `server` block. So I don't expect your existing site to work without issues.

As for adding more sites, just create more `server` blocks.

Comment: when I add more server blocks it says `nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:51` when I try to start nginx

Comment: You can't nest them. Add the new `server` block after the last one.

Comment: Take a look, I added just like that, with all the correct directories, and still it says I am not allowed to use the "server" directive.

Comment: Can you write the way it should be with the additional server block :)?

Comment: And your right, it is not so working now again...